# How to access a non-static property from another class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a non-static property inside a non-static `MainForm` class:

```
public string SelectedProfile
{
    get { return (string)cbxProfiles.SelectedItem; }
    set { cbxProfiles.SelectedItem = value; }
}
```

I would like to get the value of this property, from another non-static class. Using `MainForm.SelectedProfile` gives an error saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property".

Usually I would solve this problem by making `SelectedProfile` static, but I can't, since cbxProfiles (a ComboBox control) can't be made static.

So how do I access the property's value without making it static?

Comment: You need an instance of the `MainForm` class.

Comment: `I would like to get the value of this property, from another non-static class.` While you are creating that class pass a reference of MainForm to it. ( `new OtherClass(this)` )

Answer (score 3):

You access non-static members the same way you *always* do: by using a reference to an instance of the object.

So whatever code you want to be able to use that property, you need to pass it a reference to a `MainForm` object.

Comment: How do I get a reference to the `MainForm` object and how does this differ from the method mentioned by Otiel?

Comment: @Spioner: that's _really_ hard to say without seeing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It all depends on where that code is and what its relationship to the `MainForm` object is. In fact, much of the time I see a question like this, you don't really want for some other class to access that property; instead, the other class should be implementing an event that the `MainForm` object subscribes to, and then it just accesses its own property. But without a code example, there's no way to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the compilation error, you need to have a reference of the existing `MainForm` instance to act on it.

```
// You surely do this somewhere in your code
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
// ...
// Use the reference to your mainForm to access its public properties
String selectedProfile = mainForm.SelectedProfile;
```

Comment: Note that the above code example is unlikely to access the given property on the actual instance of `MainForm` that the OP wants to use.

Comment: I don't want to create a new `MainForm`, i just want to get the `SelectedItem` from `cbxProfiles` inside the `MainForm` that already exists. How would I do this?

Comment: You have to pass an instance of MainForm to the method which need to access the non-static property.

Comment: Edited answer after Peter's comment. @Spioner: how do you create your `MainForm` and show it in the first place ?

Comment: @Otiel I use the default way that Visual Studio provides, using `Application.Run(new MainForm)`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party but my solution might help someone someday down the road. You can directly access an open form's controls (even private ones) using `Application.OpenForms[n]`...

For example, let's assume you have created a MainForm and then created a comboBox such that it is inside MainForm => Tab (named tabControl) => TabPage (named tabPageMain) => Panel (named pnlMain) => ComboBox (named cmbSeconds). Then you can access this last control as follows:

```
ComboBox combo = Application.OpenForms[0].Controls["tabControl"].Controls["tabPageMain"].Controls["pnlMain"].Controls["cmbSeconds"] as ComboBox;
string SelectedProfile = (string)combo.SelectedItem;

// OR

bool isMaximized = Application.OpenForms[0].WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

i.e. you've got to traverse the path from the top-level form down to that particular control. **Document Outline** view of Visual Studio (*View* menu => *Other Windows* => *Document Outline*) might help you in this bcoz you might be overlooking some transparent containers in between.

Use it cautiously. For example, if the handles of any of the referenced controls are not yet created, you might see runtime exceptions.