# How to use values from another class

Tags: c#

I would like to have a class or whatever else is better where I store constant values that I want to use in other classes.

For example, I would like to have a class named A which looks like

```
public class A
{
  public int x = 1;
}
```

and in another class I would like to use that value in a method:

```
class B
{
  public void test()
  {
    int y = A.x;
  }
}
```

I know this is wrong, it's just an example of what I would like to use. It's probably a basic question but I don't have much experience with programming.

Comment: `I don't have much experience with programming.` then start to learn from the scratch: [Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

Comment: Or declare `X` as a [static](https://www.dotnetperls.com/static-property) property.

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do that? Never used getters before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a non-static property from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917420/how-to-access-a-non-static-property-from-another-class)

Comment: Hardcoded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the bad practice to declare everything public. Access modifiers set the accessibility of method, class or variables. Meanwhile There are four pillars of Object Oriented Programming. **Abstraction**, **Inheritance**, **Polymorphism** and **Encapsulation**. You should learn them for better and good understanding of programming, link is provided here. [OOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming)

Hope this will surely help you.

Meanwhile in your question, if you really need to access behavior or method of class A, you can make it static and access in another class.

```
public class A{

    public static int x = 1; 
    public static void print(){
        //some code here
    }
}

public class B{

    public void test(){
        int a = A.x;
        A.print();
    }
}
```

Or another method is to make x private and make getter and setter of it. Initialize instance of A in class B and access it through its instance.

```
A obj = new A();
int a = obj.getX();
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the OP's question as it does not answer his question but points out a valid issue with beginner development practices.

Comment: @davisj1691 i think, it's now a proper answer and didn't deserve a down vote :)

Comment: Just following the guidelines on that one; did but does no more. The update looks more relevant to the issue at hand!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of class `A` within class `B` in order to access it's properties (or in your case it's field `x`).

```
internal class A {
    public int X { get; set; } = 1;
}
internal class B {
    private A myInstanceOfA = new A();
    public void test() {
        int y = myInstanceOfA.X;
    }
}
```

You can however, access static and constant members of class `A` without creating a local instance:

```
internal class A {
    public const int X = 1;
}
internal class B {
    public void test() {
        int y = A.X;
    }
}
```

I would heavily recommend you look at the following articles:

- [Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)
- [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)
- [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)
- [Static Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)
- [Constant Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const)

Those should give you a thorough introduction to classes and the members contained within them.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a [`const`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const) or [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) variable, where you can define a value and access it without initializing the class.

With your example, it would be something like this:

```
public class A {
    public const Int32 ConstantVariable = 0;

    // or

    public static Int32 StaticVariable = 0;
}

public class B {
    public void test() {
        Int32 y = A.ConstantVariable;

        // or

        Int32 y = A.StaticVariable;
    }
}
```

Be aware that `const` variables need to be initialized with a value on the spot and cannot change value, whilst `static` variables can be assigned in run-time and changed whenever you want.

Comment: I disagree that what the OP needs is a `const` or `static` member for this. I believe the OP may not understand the idea of OOP yet.

Comment: From what the OP wrote, it seems that the intention is to create a generic class to store global variables, like a config class. So `const` \ `static` are what the OP needs.

Comment: Just curious as to how you believe the intent is to create something similar to a config class? The OP clearly states a lack of experience with development. Also, wouldn't your global config class be static also (not just it's members)? `internal static class Config`